# Matching objects incorrectly serialized by Lua's cjson with Spring Data Redis

Tags: spring, redis, lua, jackson, spring-data-redis

I'm having a problem that seems like it should be common enough to have a standard solution but I still haven't been able to find one.

Lua is uncapable of distinguishing empty arrays from empty objects since both are represented by tables. The problem is that redis' included by default json library (cjson) will always serialize empty arrays as empty objects. When I return these objects, since Jackson is at the other end expecting for a list, deserialization fails.

Some possible solutions:

- Compiling redis with a different version of cjson, which seems like too much effort
- Telling Jackson to accept an empty object as an empty list, but I don't know how.

Does anyone have a solution? Could I provide some Jackson configuration that allows it to accept empty objects as lists?